# "EPERM: operation not permitted, rename" when using express session with session-file-store

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I'm creating a node application that runs on `express` webserver with `express-session` and `session-file-store` for session management.

Ever since I included this in my project my debug console is filled with errors like:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'd:\nodejs\project\sessions\924bcb22-dd42-47d1-a790-91ea14fe4cf1.json.3130939431' -> 'd:\nodejs\project\sessions\924bcb22-dd42-47d1-a790-91ea14fe4cf1.json'
```

Regardless of the error everything seems to be in working order (session persists after window/browser closing as expected, etc.) however these errors make it really difficult to properly debug the output from the server as they're constantly repeating.

I've looked far and wide for a solution, tried downgrading the module, running both VS Code as Admininistrator and standalone app through Administrative PowerShell, checking file permissions on the folder so everyone and everything can read/write yet the errors keep showing. Additionally, a lot of similar errors I've looked through the internet show the same error but have nothing to `session-file-store`, some don't even use `express` at all.

in case it's useful, here's a summary of app.js which might help resolve this:

```
//...
const express               = require('express');
const session               = require('express-session');
const FileStore             = require('session-file-store')(session);


const http                  = require('http');
const path                  = require('path');
const socketio              = require('socket.io');
const bodyParser            = require('body-parser');

const app                   = express();
const server                = http.createServer(app);
global.io                   = socketio(server);
const port                  = process.env.PORT || 453;

//...

app.use(session({
  genid: (req) => {
    return global.uuid()
  },
  store: new FileStore(),
  secret: 'NotReallyMySecretKey',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))
```

Please note that I've also looked through a lot of answers here on SO, and even though they're even named similarly, I don't find any similarities between them, so please check before flagging the question as a duplicate.

Thank you for your assistance on the matter!

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem and I too looked through SO and related sites. I solved this after looking through and reading documentation.

In my case when static files were shared, it would initialize a session and for some reason it would fail and cause that error. I also got the cannot write headers error.

You have to keep your static files in express at the top of the middleware stack. It goes just below pug and before everything else.

Example -

```
/**
 * Add views
 */
app.set("views",path.join(__dirname,"views"));
app.set("view engine","pug");

const myMiddlewares = [
//THIS HAS TO BE ON THE TOP.
express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'www')),
cookieParser("mySecret"),
session({
  store: new fileStore(fileStoreOptions),
  secret:"mySecret",
  resave : true,
  saveUninitialized: false
}),
bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }),
bodyParser.json(),
upload.array(),
compression(),
passport.initialize(),
passport.session(),
flash()
];
app.use(myMiddlewares);
```

Link to the documentation
https://gist.github.com/joepie91/c0069ab0e0da40cc7b54b8c2203befe1